# Pass Text Between Activities

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Passing data between activities in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965109/passing-data-between-activities-in-android)

How can I edit text in my Activity, then pass this text by an intent to a new Activity?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965109/passing-data-between-activities-in-android , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643243/passing-data-between-activities

Answer (score 6):

You can pass extra data via the intent using `intent.putExtra("key", text_field.getText().toString())` on the intent before you send it (in the first activity) and `getIntent().getExtras().getString("key")` in the second activity.

This is assuming `text_field` is your `EditText` you want to pass the value from. You can change `"key"` to whatever you want, too.

Comment: fine i will do it now !! but how can i save an text i edit it in one activity For example !! i want to Enter my name then in edit text field i want to write my name then it will be saved ?!!! can this happen ?

Comment: @Joja Ingy, if I understand you correctly, take a look at [data storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

Comment: String FILENAME = "hello_file";
String string = "hello world!";

FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();

Comment: where can i put it !! or implement the data storage in my code

Comment: @Joja it is clear why: there are other questions dealing with the same issue, so look at the those answers and you'll get yours. To avoid getting qustions closed, please search SO before posting a question.